# How do I ignore PHP Notice: json_decode(): integer overflow detected in Yii?

Tags: php, json, yii, yii2

I'm trying to decode a long integer in JSON, but it always crashes and gives an error in Yii. I already use the `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` option. How do I bypass this error or ignore it?

```
php > var_dump( json_decode('[66933258,"B009GQ034C",281441845828]', false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
PHP Notice:  json_decode(): integer overflow detected in php shell code on line 1
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(66933258)
  [1]=>
  string(10) "B009GQ034C"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "9223372036854775807"
}
```

In the app, it gives

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>   json_decode(): integer overflow detected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried your code and on my machine it works perfectly, perhaps it has something to do with your php version or so?

The only thing I can think of is (if you don't need the values as a number, but just the values) to use `preg_replace` to "escape" the numbers as strings first:

```
$json = '[66933258,"B009GQ034C",281441845828]'; 
var_dump(json_decode(preg_replace('/(\W)(\d+)(\W)/', '\\1"\\2"\\3', $json)));
```

Will yield this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '66933258' (length=8)
  1 => string 'B009GQ034C' (length=10)
  2 => string '281441845828' (length=12)
```

Edit:

Now that I'm looking a bit closer: You are actually getting a value on the command line. So the `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is working correctly. The problem is that the `json_decode()`-function seems to generate a notice before it switches to this behavior. Yii's error handler captures notices by default and converts them into an exception.

In this case the solution might be as simple as:

```
var_dump(@json_decode('[66933258,"B009GQ034C",281441845828]', false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

I would normally advise against using the silence operator because it obscures errors, but in this case it beats the alternative (disabling capturing notices and possibly missing other errors)

Comment: I have `PHP 5.6.7 (cli) (built: Mar 20 2015 13:17:28)`. That's a good idea. I ended up converting the values to string during the encoding. I think it's a problem with Yii because it is only a notice on the console.

Comment: Removed my previous comment and edited my answer as you are right... It's because of Yii's error handler also treating notices as fatal errors.

Comment: Well, technically they are still there, but they are silenced. Use responsibly I would say. This can cause bugs that are very hard to find, which is why using that operator is a bit frowned upon ;)

Answer (score 0):

Surround with try/catch statement to intercept the exception.  More points for selecting the proper exception to catch, and preventing false positives from similar exceptions.

Comment: Ok I captured the exception, but it's not parsing the JSON in Yii. It doesn't assign the variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use json_decode() with depth[512] and option[JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING] for large integers :

```
<?php
    $json = '{"number": 12345678901234567890}';

    $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

    $jsonObject = json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

    print_r($jsonArray);
?>
```

**JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING** that allows casting big integers to string instead of floats which is the default.